# Unity Interception Configuration - how to make less verbose?

Tags: .net, configuration, unity-container, app-config, configuration-files

To set up interception in Unity 2.0 you put something like this in your config (taken from Unity documentation)...

```
      <policy name="addDataAccessTypes">
        <matchingRule name="DataLayerMatch" type="NamespaceMatchingRule">
          <constructor>
            <param name="namespaceName" value="MyApp.DataAccess" />
          </constructor>
        </matchingRule>
        <callHandler name="LogHandler" type="LoggingCallHandler" />
        <callHandler name="SecurityHandler"
            type="DatabaseSecurityCheckHandler" />
      </policy>
```

Is there a way to set up multiple interfaces for inteception with the same handling class?

E.g. something like this...

```
<constructor>
    < interface to intercept 1 />
    < interface to intercept 2 />
</construtor>
```

With the method given in the unity example your config file becomes very verbose if you have a lot of interfaces to intercept.

Answer (score 2):

You can do interceptions with attributes in a more fluent manner if you use the `Unity.Interception` assembly. The downside to this is the intercepted class does (in some way) know about the aspect:

A very quick example of the setup looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting test...");

            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
            container.Configure<Interception>()
                .SetDefaultInterceptorFor<IGadget>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

            container.RegisterType<IGadget, Gadget>();

            var gadget = container.Resolve<IGadget>();
            gadget.DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred: {0}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Test complete.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}



public class LogAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container.Resolve<LogHandler>();
    }
}

public class LogHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Logging the action! -{0}-", input.MethodBase.Name);
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }
}

public interface IGadget
{
    void DoSomething();
}

[Log]
public class Gadget : IGadget
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tI did something!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but need to do it in config.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Do you mean you're restricted to doing it in the config for some reason? I was offering my solution as an alternative to having to do any setups in the config file.